# Fancybox V2 fit content width iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe, fancybox-2

I've been trying to have the iframe from fancybox v2 fit the width of my content. It always displays the content to big in the iframe and i have to horizontal scroll to see the rest of the content. I would like to view the whole width of the content in the iframe without having to scroll. How would i approach this solution?

ive tried this but doesnt work.

```
 $(".fancybox").fancybox({
     maxWidth: 992
   });
```

See- http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

Comment: I am not sure to understand if fancybox should adapt to the `width` of the content -OR- the content should adapt to the `width` of fancybox. If the first, if the content is wider than the viewport, there is no way you can avoid the horizontal scroll bars. If the second, you can set a `maxWidth` of `90%` to fancybox so it will never expand bigger than the viewport AND if you have control over the page opened in the iframe, you can make it responsive and set a `width` of `100%` to the body tag so it will always fit in fancybox regarding the size of the latest, does it make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing maxWidth,try width-

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
 width: 992,
 height:992
});
```